# How do I setup wdb for Pre-Kernel debugging in vxworks 6.7?

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, vxworks

I am new to the RTOS world and working on the eval version of vxworks 6.7. I don't know How to turn on the wdb debugging for my bootloader which has troubles loading my network driver. I hope someone can help me with a quick tips.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you connected via serial for debugging? If not, it may be impossible to debug networking issues.  wdb runs on host in eclipse and connects to device (target) via serial or ethernet.
Anyway you turn on wdb support via the project when you build the bootloader.

Comment: Yes, I have serial port connected to the target and on the other end my WB machine is connected using the target server. My problem is I followed this a post here yesterday, but didn't get me anywhere. My understanding is that if I configured my bootrom.bin correctly for wdb per-kernel initialization, it should boot up, stop execution and wait for the wdb client to connect to it. This doesn't happen, and the bootrom.sys just continue execution and goes on to the auto booting process. The link I followed yesterday and didn't work for me is here:

Comment: The Link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181011/how-do-i-use-the-vxworks-debug-agent-to-perform-pre-kernel-debugging